# Restrict web access above a given directory (Apache 2.0 & suPHP)

Tags: apache-2.2, file-permissions, suphp

How do I restrict web access to parent folders of the main website directory. For example if I have the following directories/files:

```
/
├── home
│   └── user
│   │   ├── img.png
│   │   ├── script.js
│   │   └── page.html
└── var
    └── www
        └── index.html
```

and [www.example.com](http://www.google.com) points to `/var/www/`, I don't `/var/www/index.html` to be able to access any files outside, in this case, `img.png`, `script.js`, `page.html`.

A few extra notes:

- I am using `suPHP` so I can't go around and change permissions/owners to restrict access.
- suPHP does not work with htaccess files[[1]](http://www.technibble.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-21018.html), so I can't go around and disable `../` for the top most folder(s) [[2]](http://www.suphp.org/FAQ.html).
- Symbolic links must also be ignored in case `/` is linked to in `/var/www`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to enable the `check_vhost_docroot` option in order to ensure that the scripts is within DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
check_vhost_docroot=true
```

Comment: Is this in the `/etc/suphp/suphp.conf` file? If so, would this also apply to, for example `<script src="...">` statements?

Comment: It would only apply to PHP scripts (that is, anything accessed by suPHP). Anything else accessed by Apache (not suPHP) is read using the webserver user permissions.